# magento buy X get each additional 1/2 off

Tags: php, magento

Is there a way in magento to create a rule where after you buy X, each additional product you get 1/2 off?

Comment: yes there is and you can create that with cart rules. Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to handle this w/ light programming

[http://www.jamiekahgee.com/2011/11/how-to-create-a-custom-shopping-cart-rule/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120921081411/http://www.jamiekahgee.com/2011/11/how-to-create-a-custom-shopping-cart-rule/) *(link goes to web.archive since original one is dead)*

Answer (score 0):

If there is no simple cart rule here is a HACK -

make the items you want to include in the discount to a weight of 1.
rule is weight of 2+ 50%
or 2=50% 3=50%  etc

if you use weight already pick another available variable